# Place Autocomplete Google iOS -[UIActivityIndicatorView release]: message sent to deallocated instance -

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController and there is tab bar controller child of the revel controller. When I am presenting or pushing to the AutoCompleteController https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete and dismissing it, the Auto complete still sending messages to the UIActvityView. Is there. anything I can do to dismiss it properly and dismiss all the messages.

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.delegate = self
present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)

 // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
  func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false // Crashes here 
}
```

And 
crashes here

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with the message  -[UIActivityIndicatorView release]: message sent to deallocated

Comment: not clear what your are asking ?

Comment: The app is using a SWRevealViewController as side panel or side menu. So when I presenting or pushing a Google Auto Complete View Comtroller https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete in a center view controller it crashes with message in NSZombie that message sent to deallocated instance.

Comment: `presentView` and `pushView` has nothing to do with any specific `viewControler`, it is just a way to navigate your app through all `viewVontrollers` one by one by maintaining stack of views.

Comment: update your question and tell how you are performing navigation from one to another `viewController`.

Comment: yes right. I got that answer. Now, as I dismiss a view controller, it must be removed all the observers, so that it can not receive any  message as all the view are deallocated. Some how, the message to activity view is still arising and app crashes because its deallocated.

Comment: Your question needs to be edited and more detail added.